# Rails 4.2.6 - has_many through, undefined method 'name' do nil:NilClass (ruby 2.3.0, fails only on production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have prototype model

```
class ArchMagazine::Prototype < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'arch_magazine_prototypes'

  has_many :custom_dictionaries, through: :dictionaries_prototypes, source: :custom_dictionary, foreign_key: :custom_dictionary_id
  has_many :dictionaries_prototypes, -> { where(kind: 'normal') }, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'ArchMagazine::DictionariesPrototype'
end
```

and service

```
class ArchMagazine::UpdatePrototype < ArchMagazine::PrototypeCore

  def process
    if prototype_form.valid?
      prototype.update(prototype_form.prototype_attrs)
      add_custom_dictionaries(prototype, true)
    else
      raise ValidationError.new
    end
  end

  def add_custom_dictionaries(prototype, with_destroy = false)
    prototype.custom_dictionaries.destroy_all if with_destroy
    prototype_form.custom_dictionary_ids.present? and prototype_form.custom_dictionary_ids.each do |dictionary_id|
      create_record(prototype, dictionary_id, 'normal')
    end
  end

end
```

When I'm trying to update prototype object (creating works fine) with some new custom_dictionaries_ids, application fails at

`prototype.custom_dictionaries.destroy_all if with_destroy`

Error link (not exactly mine but same active_record error): http://pastebin.com/TZugtfrd

Funny thing is that code from my example works on development just fine. **Production** is the problem. Some time before, **development** would run on **ruby 2.0.0-p195**, **rails 4.0.4** and everything were fine. Then I updated **ruby** version on **production** to **2.3** and applications started to fail. Situation repeats itself on **development** when I updated **ruby** on this environment. After that I updated **rails** on **development** to **4.2.6** and everything started to run smoothly. But nothing changes on **production** after deploying updated **rails** line in **Gemfile**.

Comment: Looks like the same error. You should double-double check your version of Ruby and Rails, and make sure you bundle update in both dev and production. Somewhere you will be on the wrong version of one or the other, all else being equal.

Comment: Add the stacktrace from production to your question.